What is the name for a seemingly rare dingbat
There is a dingbat (glyph) that I have seen twice, once in a book published in 1947 and one in an e-book (and probably in the print version) published in 2012.  In the first case it is used as a quotation mark to show long (some multi-page) quotations.  I the second it is placed on its own line between short quotations which are other-wise unmarked. I have been unable to find any information about it.  Does someone here know what this is?
I apologize for using images which are crucial for my question, as I don't know any other way to describe this glyph.



Looks like a very busted, low-grade, version of a leaf/flower dingbat. The posted enlargement doesn't look anything like what I see when I enlarge the lower image you posted.

might be a maritime flag letterpress ornament or it is a logo. The book in the pic is available on archive.org, published c. 1970 the scan is pretty good but zooming doesn't help much. There have been near infinite amounts of ornaments of this sort.

Probably of no help, but the first book is:  Great Adventures and Explorations, Vilhualmur Stefansson, ed., The Dial Press, New York, 1947.  The second (ebook) is: Bon Mots, Wisecracks, and Gags, Robert E. Drennan, Skyhorse Publishing copyright 2012.  In the ebook the gliph is inserted as a small image.  An inquiry to Skyhorse Publishing has, so far, been unanswered.
